# Update from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I can't seem to get my update from inner join method to work. I have tried to write it a few different ways to no avail. Rows get affected but the product table's values are never actually updated.

**Select code to test (should return no results after update query is run):**

```
SELECT 
    [P].[ProductCode],
    [P].[PriceSelling],
    [ID].[InclPrice],
    [P].[StockQty],
    [ID].[Qty]
FROM
    dbo.Sync_ImportData AS [ID]
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Sync_Product AS [P]
ON
    [P].[ProductCode] = [ID].[ISBN]
WHERE
    ([P].[StockQty] <> [ID].[Qty] OR [P].[PriceSelling] <> [ID].[InclPrice])
```

**Update Code:**

```
UPDATE [P]
SET
    [P].[StockQty] = [ID].[Qty],
    [P].[PriceSelling] = [ID].[InclPrice]
FROM
    dbo.Sync_Product AS [P]
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Sync_ImportData AS [ID]
ON
    [P].[ProductCode] = [ID].[ISBN] 
WHERE
    ([P].[StockQty] <> [ID].[Qty] OR [P].[PriceSelling] <> [ID].[InclPrice])
```

Basically I need to update the stock qty and price if the Imported Data a) has a record for the product (ISBN matches ProductCode) and b) either value needs to be updated (qty or price is different from ImportData)

Comment: Have you considered null values?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reasons that wouldn't operate as expected. You could use the `OUTPUT` clause as per here http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/47032/a-beginners-guide-to-the-output-clause-in-sql-server/ to confirm which rows were updated. Are the columns updated `float` by any chance?

Comment: Are you sure ProductCode matches ISBN?

Comment: No null values should match on the JOIN and WHERE clause. The weird part is that the query runs, rows are said to be affected but when the data is inspected nothing has changed. @TimSchmelter

Comment: Yes, ProductCode and ISBN will match @Donal. The datatype for the columns being compared are the same: money for InclPrice and PriceSelling and INT for Qty and StockQty

Comment: I too am dumbfounded as to why this does not work. I have tried re-arranging the query many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see this behavior if there were more than one match between the tables.  In particular, if `ISBN` is not unique in `Sync_ImportData`:

```
SELECT id.ISBN, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Sync_ImportData id
GROUP BY id.ProductCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If there are duplicates, then one of the rows would be used for the update -- arbitrarily.  The changes would not match the second row.

Comment: Gordon you are absolutely right. I have just established this huge issue with what was supposed to be a reliable datasource. Thank you for your answer. Now it is time for a scathing email :)